# Multiple Checkboxes Conditions in VBA - No Two or more Checkboxes to be selected

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I need the help with the selection of multiple checkboxes by user. I have a userform in vba that has 8 checkboxes. I want user to select only ONE checkbox at a time. What is the shortest coding possible?

Comment: You should create a Sub, let us say, "UnTickCheckBoxes" iterating between form controls, identify the check boxes and change their value in `False`, except the clicked one. This code will be called by  all check boxes `Click` event, if their value is `True`. You can manually put the call in the `Click` event code, or crete a class able to allocate it to all existing check boxes.

Comment: If only one checkbox can be selected then the typical approach would be to use radiobuttons (this is the "standard" UI for mutually-exclusive options)

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way:

1. Create a `Sub` able to untick all the check boxes, except the active one:

```
Public Sub UnTickCheckBoxes() 'Public to be also called from outside if use a class for event allocation
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 0 To Me.Controls.count - 1
        If TypeName(Me.Controls(i)) = "CheckBox" And Not ActiveControl.Name = Me.Controls(i).Name Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                 Me.Controls(i).value = False
                 Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

2. Call the above sub from the `Click` event of all check boxes. You can use `Change` event for doing something else. The call can be done in this way:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If ActiveControl.value = True Then
        UnTickCheckBoxes
    End If
End Sub
```

2 bis. Automatic event allocation to all check boxes:

2.1 Create a class named "chkBoxesClickEvent". Copy and paste in it the next code:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents chkBEvent As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub chkBEvent_Click()
    If chkBEvent.value = True Then
       chkBEvent.Parent.UnTickCheckBoxes
    End If
End Sub
```

2.2 Declare on top of the form (in the declarations area) the next variable:

```
Private chkB() As New chkBoxesClickEvent
```

2.3 Place the next code in the `UserForm_Initialize` event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   Dim C As MSForms.Control, k As Long
   ReDim chkB(Me.Controls.count): k = 1
   For Each C In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf C Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            Set chkB(k).chkBEvent = C: k = k + 1
        End If
   Next
   ReDim Preserve chkB(k - 1)
End Sub
```

Do not forget to clear all check boxes `Click` event, if any code inside...

Show the form a see how it works, then send some feedback.

Comment: @Anees Kalsekar Didn't you find some time to test the above solution? If tested, didn't it work as ou need?